# How can I find this element In Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

From this page I need to click on data-value 1

`<div class="custom-select-dropdown-value" data-value="1">1</div>`

How it can be possible? Please, I need code.

```
                            <div class="custom-select-dropdown">
                                <div class="custom-select-dropdown-inner">
                                    <div class="custom-select-dropdown-value" data-value="0">0</div>
                                    <div class="custom-select-dropdown-value" data-value="1">1</div>
                                    <div class="custom-select-dropdown-value" data-value="3">3</div>
                                    <div class="custom-select-dropdown-value" data-value="5">5</div>
                                    <div class="custom-select-dropdown-field">
                                        <input type="text" name="repeatOnErrorTimes" placeholder="0" data-type="int">
                                        <button>&gt;</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried on your own?

Answer (score -1):

Try any one of the below locators:

XPATH:

```
.//div[@class='custom-select-dropdown-value' and @data-value='1']
```

or

```
.//div[@data-value='1' and text()='1']
```

or

```
.//div[@data-value='1']
```

CSS_SELECTOR:

```
div[data-value='1']
```